# generate datastring from json object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am getting a data in json format from ajax using

```
var parsed=JSON.parse(data);
```

suppose the output is as follows

```
{"confirm_type":"contract_action","job_id":12,"id":7}
```

i want do generate a dynamic data string from the above json so that i can send these using a ajax function data.

for eg

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some.php",
  data: { confirm_type: "contract_action", job_id: 12, id:7 }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```

How to convert a json object to that format for ajax data ?

Comment: I think you can send your object as it is, no need to do anything

Comment: just pass it as `data: parsed`?

Comment: You are very right. I thought i need to convert it now. LOL. it was already done. Thank you for explaining this.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to convert the JSON object into string as shown below

```
 var parsed=JSON.parse(data);
 //use the parsed data else where in the code
 $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "some.php",
      data: JSON.stringify(parsed),
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
      });
```